# can not find out all city from germany

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I tried with this query.

```
SELECT distinct ?city ?cityName ?country  WHERE {
 ?city rdf:type dbo:City .
?city rdfs:label ?cityName.
?city dbo:country ?country.
?city dbo:country dbr:Germany.


  FILTER (lang(?cityName) = 'en')
} ORDER BY ?city
```

But some city which have `dbo:country` predicate and `dbr:Germany` value those are still not listed in the output. For example try this link http://dbpedia.org/page/Goslar . There is no "Goslar" city in output. Can anybody explain me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, dbpedia is really a messy place. For example, `Goslar`, in dbpedia, is not even a city it is a `dbo:PopulatedPlace dbo:Town  yago:City108524735` . That's why It's not in the output. Another example is `Paris`. You can check it.